# Why was Noach born after Adam's death?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation, adam, noach-noah-the-man

Noach was the [tenth](https://www.conformingtojesus.com/images/webpages/chronology_chart_from_adam_to_abraham_1.jpg) generation after Adam. The previous nine generations had been born while Adam was still alive.

Are there any mefarshim that mention why specifically Noach was the first to be born after the death of Adam?

Comment: I always assumed it was the other way round. Since Adam wasn't immortal, at some point there would be a generation born that he never got to meet. And that generation was inevitably going to be very, very corrupt given that they lacked the opportunity to meet Adam and learn from his experience.

Comment: @Zarka That can be an Interesting suggestion. Due to the generation of Noach being wicked, they did not merit the opportunity to exist at the same period as Adam.

Comment: I think even that's backwards. It's not that they didn't merit the opportunity to exist at the same time as Adam. It's that, *because* they didn't exist at the same time as Adam, they ended up wicked. See eg page 52: https://archive.org/details/chroniclesofjera00eleaiala/page/52/mode/2up

Comment: @Zarka I like it, thank you for your insight.